# android - swipe button no resource identifier found for attribute

Tags: java, android, button, swipe

I'm trying to use the swipe button which is provided by com.ebanx.swipebtn.SwipeButton

In my app gradle

```
compile 'com.ebanx:swipe-button:0.2.1'
```

In my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.ebanx.swipebtn.SwipeButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:button_image_disabled="@drawable/ic_lock_open_black_24dp"
        app:button_image_enabled="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
        app:button_background="@drawable/shape_button"
        app:button_image_height="60dp"
        app:button_image_width="100dp"
        app:button_bottom_padding="18dp"
        app:button_left_padding="38dp"
        app:button_right_padding="38dp"
        app:button_top_padding="18dp"
        app:initial_state="disabled"
        app:inner_text="Enable"
        app:inner_text_background="@drawable/shape_rounded"
        app:inner_text_color="@android:color/white"
        app:inner_text_size="16sp"
        app:inner_text_top_padding="18dp"
        app:inner_text_bottom_padding="18dp" />
```

When  try to build, I get the error which says that no resource identifier is found for attributes that begin with the app prefix, which are specific for the swipebutton view.

I tried adding the xmlns app like this

```
<com.ebanx.swipebtn.SwipeButton   
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.ebanx"
    .....
    ..... />
```

But when I run the app the swipe button doesn't show.

Comment: Hey Amine, it should work without any trouble following this example: https://github.com/ebanx/swipe-button/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/content_main.xml
can you provide more info about the error message? Thanks!